# How to data-bind to a property of a composite object in a collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpftoolkit

I need to allow selection of several items from this predefined list:

```
public enum QuarkType{
    Up,
    Down,
    [Description("Magical Being")] Charm,
    [Description("Quite Odd")] Strange,
    Top,
    Bottom
}
```

So I use [CheckComboBox](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home), and use the `DescriptionAttribute` where I need to use custom description. I feed the `CheckComboBox` using a `MarkupExtension` that returns a list of all values of the given `enum` as `IEnumerable<EnumDescriptionPair>`, where `EnumDescriptionPair` is:

```
public class EnumDescriptionPair{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is how to pass the `Value`s of this list to the code-behind list:

```
public ObservableCollection<QuarkType> SelectedQuarksList { get; set; }
```

I mean, how to take just the `Value` out of the `EnumDescriptionPair` for each item of the selected list ?

This is what I have thus far. It obviously doesn't work (meaning it shows the right strings in the `CheckComboBox`, and allows selecting several items, but isn't reflected in the `SelectedQuarksList` mentioned above):

```
<Window x:Class="MyEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:MyEditor"
        xmlns:toolKit="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <StackPanel>
        <toolKit:CheckComboBox x:Name="Ccb" Delimiter=","
                               ItemsSource="{loc:EnumItemsValueConverter {x:Type loc:QuarkType}}"
                               DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                               SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedQuarksList}" />

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedQuarksList}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Since the list is predefined, does the list of checkboxes need to be bound? I have done this before with all options declared in XAML and bound to a Enum, but not the way you are describing. +1 for a great question.

Comment: @LordTakkera - I'm not sure I understand what you suggest, but I'm open for suggestions

Comment: My attempt at explaining my suggestions are in my answer, hopefully they are of use to you.

Comment: @LordTakkera - I can't use your answer because the `enum` is subject to change - the whole idea is that we'll be able to change it often

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what your question asks, you could try using a converter on the SelectedQuarksList binding that does a ".Select(q => q.Value)" in the ConvertBack function.

To get the behavior you want, I have done this successfully in the past (example with 2 of your values), this sets up the enum as "Flags" so the value sequence goes 0, 1, 2, 4...:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Checkbox Content="Up" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedQuarksFlags, Converter={Static Resource HasFlagToBoolConverter}, ConverterParamater={x:Static Quarks.Up}}"
<Checkbox Content="Magical Being" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedQuarksFlags, Converter={Static Resource HasFlagToBoolConverter}, ConverterParamater={x:Static Quarks.Charm}}"
</StackPanel>
```

The converter looks like:

```
 Quark _lastSeenValue;
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Quark paramQuark = (Quark)parameter;
        Quark currentQuark = (Quark)value;

        _lastSeenValue = currentQuark;
        return currentQuark.HasFlag(paramQuark);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Quark newQuark = _lastSeenValue;
        Quark paramQuark = (Quark)parameter;

        if ((bool)value)
        {
            newQuark |= paramQuark; 
        }
        else
        {
            newQuark &= ~paramQuark;
        }

        _lastSeenValue = newQuark;
        return newQuark;
    }
```

This could be converted to add or remove from a list relatively easily, but I know the code above works.

Comment: Your `XAML` code above is supposed to go into the `CheckComboBox.ItemTemplate` tag?

Comment: but now I think I understand your comment on my question... then the answer is that this `enum` is by-definition transient - the whole idea is that we'll be able to change it in the future without changing the code

Comment: No, you wound't have an item template in my XAML example, as it looks like you figured out. As far as changing it goes, unless it is data-driven, you are going to be changing code anyways :). That said, did you try using a converter with .Select?